# Why floats so weird in mariaDB?

Tags: sql, floating-point, mariadb

I had strange behaviour of MariaDB updates.
Field val if FLOAT:
    `val FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,`

Working query: `UPDATE tabe1 SET val=17111400 WHERE table1.pk=1`
But if I try to set val which decremented or incremented by one (17111399 or 17111401) - updates 0 rows.

Official documentation of MariaDB says max float is:
`3.402823466E+38`

This is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out with my collegue (great thanks!).

by default, mysql allocate ~2 bytes for number and ~2 for power (~ because 1 bit for sign and so on).
Then, `2^16 = 65536`, there is max number that we can have before E in float number. 
The number `17111400` from example stores as `1,7111400E7`
So, if we update number, and set sign, which ordinal position number more than 4 after comma - mysql thought that it is same number and UPDATE fails.

Comment: Right idea, wrong details.  1 bit for sign, 8 bits for exponent (power of 2), 24 bits for mantissa, the leading bit is 'always' 1, so it is not actually stored.  24 bits gives _about_ 7 significant digits of precision, you need 8.  What is happening is that the internal representation of 17111399 is rounded to 24 bits, giving 17111400 again.

Comment: Use DOUBLE or DECIMAL(m,n) or INT.

Comment: Thanks for giving deep understanding of process